# How to know the contrapositive of a compound logical expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

In simple expressions like: $p \implies q $ the contrapositive would be: $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$. But in other cases where the expression gets more complex: ($p \land q) \implies (\lnot q \lor p)$.

**Can we find the contrapositive of compound logical expressions like the one mentioned and if so how?**

Comment: Do you know what the negation of for example $p\wedge q$ is?

Comment: Well it would be $\lnot(\lnot q \lor p) \implies \lnot(p \land q)$.  Which requires simplifying $\lnot(\lnot q \lor p)$ and $ \lnot(p \land q)$.

Comment: The "rule" is simply: $\varphi \to \psi$ is equivalent to $\lnot \psi \to \lnot \varphi$, where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are *formulae* whatever. Then you can use logical equivalences, like [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), to "move inside" the negation sign, if needed.

Comment: It might help to say out aloud "the contrapositive is: not this implies not this", where the first "this" points to the ((not q) or p) and the second "this" points to the (p and q).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as in the normal case, but now you have to simplify some more. So as you say, in general the contrapositive of $p\implies q$ is $\neg q\implies \neg p$. For the statement $(p\wedge q)\implies(\neg q\vee p)$, let us say that $A=p\wedge q$ and $B=\neg q\vee p$. Then you know what to do, because the contrapositive is simply $\neg B\implies\neg A$. But we know that $\neg A=\neg(p\wedge q)=\neg p\vee\neg q$ and $\neg B=\neg\neg q\wedge\neg p=q\wedge\neg p$, so we get $q\wedge\neg p\implies\neg p\vee\neg q$. This of course generalizes to any set of expressions.

**Edit to answer to your last comment.**

To take the contrapositive of $(r\wedge p)\implies(r\vee q)\implies (r\wedge q)$, you should first of all put some brackets to clarify what you mean exactly. The convention is that this means
\begin{equation}
(r\wedge p)\implies((r\vee q)\implies(r\wedge q)).
\end{equation}
The contrapositive of that expression is then simply
\begin{equation}
(\neg((r\vee q)\implies(r\wedge q)))\implies(\neg(r\wedge p))
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
(\neg(r\wedge q)\implies\neg(r\vee q))\implies(\neg r\vee\neg p)
\end{equation}
which is then finally
\begin{equation}
((\neg r\vee\neg q)\implies(\neg r\wedge\neg q))\implies(\neg r\vee\neg p)
\end{equation}
assuming I have made no silly typos. However you can check this yourself, because once again, this is all the same as the simple $A\implies B$, it's just that $A$ and $B$ might be more complicated expressions, but they can all be brought back to the simple form you know what to do with, and I advise you to write this out clearly for yourself to get some practice and to see what's going on.

Comment: In $\lnot B$ why $\lnot \lnot q \land \lnot p$ = $q \land p$?

Comment: Typo, fixed it.

Comment: I tried take the contrapositive of this expression:  $(r \land p) \implies (r \lor q) \implies (r \land q)$; contrapositive: $(r \lor q) \implies \lnot (r \land q) \implies \lnot (r \land p)$. Were did I go wrong here?

Comment: Regarding the contrapositive of $(r \lor q) \implies \lnot (r \land q) \implies \lnot (r \land p)$ using the truth table to check if the contrapositive is equal to the original expression, it is not equal. Why is that?